# Задача: преобразование строки из верблюжьего регистра в змеиный

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно преобразовать строку из верблюжьего регистра в змеиный, добавить возможность менять разделитель.
Я решил задачу, но хотел бы узнать каким способом правильнее ее решить.

```py
def camel_to_snake(str, sep=' '):
    snake_register = ''
    for i in str:
        if i.isupper():
            snake_register += sep + i.lower()
        else:
            snake_register += i
    print(snake_register.lstrip(sep))

camel_register = 'ThisIsCamelCased'
camel_to_snake(camel_register, '_')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше сделать разделитель по умолчанию подчеркиванием, тогда не нужно будет каждый раз указывать. Ну и лучшего все-таки `return`, чем `print`.

```
def camel_to_snake(str, sep='_'):
    snake_register = ''
    for i in str:
        if i.isupper():
            snake_register += sep + i.lower()
        else:
            snake_register += i
    return snake_register.lstrip(sep)

camel_register = 'ThisIsCamelCased'
print(camel_to_snake(camel_register))
```

Comment: хорошо, а вот по самой логике? может есть решение короче или более понятное. у меня такое чувство что я огород нагородил

Comment: Да неплохо. Только надо ещё решить, что делать с числами, если он в тексте встретятся. Отделять только с одной стороны или с двух.

Comment: Это да, но если задуматься то можно кучу проверок сделать на все возможные виды строк, но я пока сделал то что в задаче было указано. Читаю "Как устроен Python. Гид для разработчиков, программистов и интересующихся.  М. Харрисон (2019)"

Answer (score 4):

Так, в копилку добавлю:

```
import re
a = "ThisIsCamelCaseExample"
b=list(a)
[b.insert(x,'_') for x in [m.start() for m in re.finditer("[A-Z]",a)][:0:-1]]
res = ''.join(b).lower()
print(res)
```

this_is_camel_case_example

Comment: Ого! Регулярные выражения для меня сейчас это круто!))

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если речь идет только про названия из букв английского алфавита, то можно так

```py
import string

example = 'ThisIsCamelCaseExample'

def to_snake_case(value, delimiter='_'):
  value = value[0].lower() + value[1:]
  for x in string.ascii_uppercase:
      value = value.replace(x, delimiter + x.lower())
  return value  


print(to_snake_case(example))
```

Comment: Интересно, стоило загуглить что делает ascii_uppercase и я понял как все работает. И ни какой проверки не нужно.

Comment: Вот только не пойму как эта строчка работает for x in string.ascii_uppercase. Как она перебирает значения из value

Comment: Получается она перебирает весь алфавит и заменят только совпадения в value

Comment: @TUfeed13 *>>Вот только не пойму ... перебирает значения из value* - Она перебирает значения не из `value`, а из `string.ascii_uppercase`. Т.е. на каждой **итерации цикла** в `x` находится какая-то заглавная латинская буква. А далее в `value` заменяются все эти заглавные буквы `x` на `"_" + нижний_регистр(x)`.

Comment: В случае, если на какой-либо итерации в `x` находится заглавная буква, которой нет в `value`,  то метод `replace` просто ничего не изменит.

Answer (score 1):

Может не стоит прибегать к циклу?
Мне в данной ситуации больше нравится регулярка с опережающей проверкой, тогда функция получается в одну строку.

```py
import re
def camel_to_snake(str, sep='_'):
    return re.sub('(?<=[a-zA-Z])([A-Z])',(sep + '\g<1>'),str).lower()

camel_to_snake('ThisIsCamelCased')
camel_to_snake('ThisIsCamelCased','=')
```

Кстати вы не пояснили, что вы хотите делать с заглавными буквами, идущими подряд.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]